# Android rotating wheel set end point

Tags: java, android, rotation

I was having some problem when trying to do a rotating wheel in Android. I researched online and found some solution which work. Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  //Get the content resolver
    cResolver = getContentResolver();

    //Get the current window
    window = getWindow();

    // load the image only once
    if (imageOriginal == null) {
        imageOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.wheel);
    }

    // initialize the matrix only once
    if (matrix == null) {
        matrix = new Matrix();
    } else {
        // not needed, you can also post the matrix immediately to restore the old state
        matrix.reset();
    }

    detector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());

    // there is no 0th quadrant, to keep it simple the first value gets ignored
    quadrantTouched = new boolean[] { false, false, false, false, false };

    allowRotating = true;

    dialer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_ring);
    txtWheel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtWheel);
    dialer.setOnTouchListener(new MyOnTouchListener());
    dialer.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // method called more than once, but the values only need to be initialized one time
            if (dialerHeight == 0 || dialerWidth == 0) {
                dialerHeight = dialer.getHeight();
                dialerWidth = dialer.getWidth();

                // resize
                Matrix resize = new Matrix();
                resize.postScale((float)Math.min(dialerWidth, dialerHeight) / (float)imageOriginal.getWidth(), (float)Math.min(dialerWidth, dialerHeight) / (float)imageOriginal.getHeight());
                imageScaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageOriginal, 0, 0, imageOriginal.getWidth(), imageOriginal.getHeight(), resize, false);

                // translate to the image view's center
                float translateX = dialerWidth / 2 - imageScaled.getWidth() / 2;
                float translateY = dialerHeight / 2 - imageScaled.getHeight() / 2;
                matrix.postTranslate(translateX, translateY);

                dialer.setImageBitmap(imageScaled);
                dialer.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void rotateDialer(float degrees) {
    matrix.postRotate(degrees, dialerWidth / 2, dialerHeight / 2);  
    dialer.setImageMatrix(matrix);
}

private double getAngle(double xTouch, double yTouch) {
    double x = xTouch - (dialerWidth / 2d);
    double y = dialerHeight - yTouch - (dialerHeight / 2d);

    switch (getQuadrant(x, y)) {
        case 1:
            return Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;

        case 2:
        case 3:
            return 180 - (Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI);

        case 4:
            return 360 + Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;

        default:
            // ignore, does not happen
            return 0;
    }
}

private static int getQuadrant(double x, double y) {
    if (x >= 0) {
        return y >= 0 ? 1 : 4;
    } else {
        return y >= 0 ? 2 : 3;
    }
}

private class MyOnTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private double startAngle;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                // reset the touched quadrants
                for (int i = 0; i < quadrantTouched.length; i++) {
                    quadrantTouched[i] = false;
                }

                allowRotating = false;

                startAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                double currentAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
                rotateDialer((float) (startAngle - currentAngle));
                startAngle = currentAngle;

                txtWheel.setText("" + Math.round(startAngle));
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                allowRotating = true;
                break;
        }

        // set the touched quadrant to true
        quadrantTouched[getQuadrant(event.getX() - (dialerWidth / 2), dialerHeight - event.getY() - (dialerHeight / 2))] = true;

        detector.onTouchEvent(event);

        return true;
    }
}

private class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        // get the quadrant of the start and the end of the fling
        int q1 = getQuadrant(e1.getX() - (dialerWidth / 2), dialerHeight - e1.getY() - (dialerHeight / 2));
        int q2 = getQuadrant(e2.getX() - (dialerWidth / 2), dialerHeight - e2.getY() - (dialerHeight / 2));

        // the inversed rotations
        if ((q1 == 2 && q2 == 2 && Math.abs(velocityX) < Math.abs(velocityY))
                || (q1 == 3 && q2 == 3)
                || (q1 == 1 && q2 == 3)
                || (q1 == 4 && q2 == 4 && Math.abs(velocityX) > Math.abs(velocityY))
                || ((q1 == 2 && q2 == 3) || (q1 == 3 && q2 == 2))
                || ((q1 == 3 && q2 == 4) || (q1 == 4 && q2 == 3))
                || (q1 == 2 && q2 == 4 && quadrantTouched[3])
                || (q1 == 4 && q2 == 2 && quadrantTouched[3])) {

            dialer.post(new FlingRunnable(-1 * (velocityX + velocityY)));
        } else {
            // the normal rotation
            dialer.post(new FlingRunnable(velocityX + velocityY));
        }

        return true;
    }
}

private class FlingRunnable implements Runnable {

    private float velocity;

    public FlingRunnable(float velocity) {
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (Math.abs(velocity) > 5 && allowRotating) {
            rotateDialer(velocity / 75);
            velocity /= 1.0666F;

            // post this instance again
            dialer.post(this);
        }
    }
}
```

With these code, the rotating wheel can be rotated and the degrees are correct. However, I wanted to do it in this way, it can rotate only from 0 to 360 and it should stop at 360 and I can perform a inverse rotation.

With the code above, it can rotate from 0 to 360 and go pass 360 and restarts with 0 again. I was wondering how can I stop at 360?

Thanks in advance.